# disable css/Style on Visual Studio Design Surface while designing asp.net form

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

did any one know how do i disable css/style on the visual stdio 2010 design surface.

for example.

i have this button on my aspx page

```
<asp:Button id="btnShowPopup_Collateral" runat="server" style="display:none" />
```

i have put the style on the button to hide it on the webpage. but its does not even show on the visual studio design surface. i hope you guys understand what i m trying to ask.

i m new to visual studio 2010

thanks kay

Comment: I assume the studio is showing you what it should be if you don't see it. I don't use VS at all. Not quite sure your question either.

Answer (score 0):

The design page only shows controls that are visible on page load. Since you have set your control to be invisible, it will not appear on the design page. This is also true if you have controls in a  that you have hidden. I don't know of anyway to turn off styles on the design page, but since the page is rendered from the  in the codeing page, turning off that styles would most likely leave you with nothing.

If you absolutely must see the button on the design page, i suggest leaving out the hidden snippet while designing and putting it back in when testing the page etc. If you absolutely MUST show it on the design without changing the code, then set the property so it is visible, and go to the form_load code behind page where you can set that control to hidden there. Then your design page will show the button, but when the page loads it hides again. This is most likely a poor technique and definitely won't win any "best practice" awards though.

Sorry for the super late reply, but better late than never i guess.